# trigo substitution and identites?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

When I use trigo substitution to solve an integral I get an expression like that:

$$\frac{1}{4}\tan\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{x-2}{2}\right)\right)+C$$

How can I simplify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Draw a geometric representation of $\alpha = \arcsin((x-2)/2)$, i.e. a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse $2$ and one side $x-2$. Mark where the angle $\alpha$ would be.

Now find the length of the 3rd side using Pythagorean Theorem and compute $\tan \alpha$ directly from the triangle.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=\arcsin\dfrac{x-2}2\implies\sin y=\dfrac{x-2}2$

As $-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2,\cos y\ge0$

$\cos y=+\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{x-2}2\right)^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}2$

$\tan\left(\arcsin\dfrac{x-2}2\right)=\tan(y)=\dfrac{\sin y}{\cos y}=?$

Comment: +1 clever use of algebra, but to me geometry was more intuitive...